# Web api versioning method

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I have read many links over the internet about web api versioning and every blog post or resource I have found is very clear about how to implement this feature.

However, unfortunately, I have to implement this feature for an API which is already in production and that does not respect any of the solutions I have read until now.

This API has a base address like `http://api.server.com` and handle more than one resource. These resource all have been routed by ASP.NET attribute routing like `{resource}/{id}`. For example

> POST http://api.server.com/peoples/new
>
> GET http://api.server.com/peoples/5

Actually the web api configuration is very simple like the following

```
// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I have been assigned the task to reenginer this api and would like to create and implement a new versioning scheme that sits side by side to the existing one.

I would like to use the url versioning method in a way that next realease will have the version in the url like

> POST http://api.server.com/{version}/peoples
>
> GET http://api.server.com/{version}/peoples/5

and implement a better adherence to restful recommendations in this new version (like removing the verb from the url for example).

How can I obtain this? Could you give some recommendations, examples or link to read which explain how to implement this feature and leave the actual version working?

Comment: add new route remove api with something new like apiv2 and on new methods define route [Route("apiv2/CreateInsured/{id}")]

Comment: IMHO, if its _side x side_ then your versioned urls should be ok. You can "announce" future support/features and deprecation schedules as needed.

Comment: you can add a new routing as   /api/v2/{controller}/{id}. and leave the current one as it is. However, when someone call your current version, you can assign HTTP 301 status code in the response including the v2 new url  of each api call to let users know that urls are permanently moved to new locations.